# menuitem blink on action bar when broadcast comes

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view, android-menu

I am trying to implement push notification using GCM. On my activity where I get the broadcast, I want to blink a menuitem so that user know that there is something waiting to be read.

I tried the following code:-

```
Animation mAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
mAnimation.setDuration(200);
mAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
mAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE); 
menuItem.startAnimation(mAnimation);
```

However the last line gives me error, it says "The method startAnimation is undefined for menuItem", which is true as I implemented it for button so what I did, I typecasted it to View and altered the last line with

```
((View) menuAlert).startAnimation(mAnimation);
```

However its gives me Class cast exception. How can I make this menuitem flashing.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplication()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                ImageView iv = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagelayout,
                null);

                Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplication(),
                R.anim.alert_rotate);
                rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
                rotation.setDuration(200);
                iv.startAnimation(rotation);
                menuAlert.setVisible(true);
                menuAlert.setActionView(iv);
                iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        menuAlert.getActionView().clearAnimation();
                        menuAlert.setActionView(null);
                        lbltitle.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                        lbltitle.setText(Html.fromHtml("<u>" +broadcastTitle +"</u>"));
                        lblMessage.loadData(broadcastMessage, "text/html", "UTF-8");
                        m.setVisible(false);
                        k.setVisible(false);
                        menuAlert.setVisible(false);

                    }
                });
```

I made a resource layout, where I put a Imageview then I made a animation resource for rotation and then I wrote above code and it did work.

Comment: Yes because MenuItem is not a view.

Comment: That I got it by now....however my question is how would I able to blink or flash a menuitem?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this Saty?

Answer (score 2):

Check this out.

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);

        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(this);
        imgView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        item.setActionView(imgView);

        imgView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(HorizontalScrollView.this, "onCLicked imgView", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Animation mAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
                mAnimation.setDuration(200);
                mAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                mAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
                mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);

                MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
                item.getActionView().startAnimation(mAnimation);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanx I did try to make it work but the image or animation does not show up.

Please see the edited code now and that is working for rotation animation.